# Javascript Function not working in Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I created a function in Javascript

```js
function addName(okDelete = true){

 amountExtraStudents++;
 if(amountExtraStudents > 2){
 
  preisAktuell = 60;
 
 }
 if(!okDelete){
  jQuery('#teilnehmerExtra').append('<div class="teilnehmer-1"></div>');
 }else{
  jQuery('#teilnehmerExtra').append('<div class="teilnehmer-2"></div>');
 }
 eintragNummer++; 
 updateButtons();
 
}
```

But in Edge I get this error:

[image]

In Safari I dont get any Error - but the Function  - and all the other functions in the rest of the Script Block are not working.

It works out fine in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but not in Safari, IE and Edge...

Is there something incompatible with the Browser?

Comment: Why you have an expression as parameter?

Comment: In ES6 it's good stuff, but anything before that it's no good. @SimonSchüpbach

Comment: Isnt that giving the possibility to set a "standard" value, if no parameter is given?

Comment: Should only work in Chrome or FF, surprised it works in Safari? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @chillNUT - it doesnt work in Safari!
Any work Around?

Comment: As others have noted, this feature isn't supported in Edge yet. [This is a good resource](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for seeing what features are available in different environments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is occuring when you use the '[default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)' feature [introduced in ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation). Edge [does not support it](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

An ES5 version would be:

```
function addName(okDelete){
    if (typeof okDelete === "undefined") {
        okDelete = true;
    }
```

You might also consider using a tool such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your ES6 into ES5.

Comment: Was editing my answer without realizing you beat me, oops! +1, this is the answer OP wants.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is working out fine - I didnt know, that this is not possible in ES5... :)